# Юнити жалуется на ошибку в Json файле

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Учу сериализацию данных с помощью json файла (примерно так должно называться). Хочу сохранять, ну, допустим, тексты заданий по информатике с их ответами. Json файл содержит следующий текст:

```json
{
    "all_tasks": {
        "IT_task": [
            {
                "tasks": [

                    "В одной из кодировок Unicode каждый символ кодируется 16 битами. Вова написал текст (в нём нет лишних пробелов):
«Ёж, лев, слон, олень, тюлень, носорог, крокодил, аллигатор — дикие животные».
Ученик вычеркнул из списка название одного из животных. Заодно он вычеркнул ставшие лишними запятые и пробелы — два пробела не должны идти подряд.
При этом размер нового предложения в данной кодировке оказался на 16 байтов меньше, чем размер исходного предложения. Напишите в ответе вычеркнутое название животного.",   
        
            "В одной из кодировок Unicode каждый символ кодируется 16 битами. Ваня написал текст (в нём нет лишних пробелов):
«Уфа, Азов, Пермь, Белово, Вологда, Камбарка, Соликамск — города России».
Ученик вычеркнул из списка название одного из городов. Заодно он вычеркнул ставшие лишними запятые и пробелы — два пробела не должны идти подряд.
При этом размер нового предложения в данной кодировке оказался на 22 байта меньше, чем размер исходного предложения. Напишите в ответе вычеркнутое название города России.",              

             "В одной из кодировок Unicode каждый символ кодируется 32 битами. Алёша написал текст (в нём нет лишних пробелов):
«Ток, фата, шляпа, колпак, диадема, кокошник - головные уборы».
Ученик вычеркнул из списка название одного из головных уборов. Заодно он вычеркнул ставшие лишними запятые и пробелы — два пробела не должны идти подряд.
При этом размер нового предложения в данной кодировке оказался на 24 байта меньше, чем размер исходного предложения. Напишите в ответе вычеркнутое название головного убора.",         

             "В одной из кодировок Unicode каждый символ кодируется 8 битами. Слава написал текст (в нём нет лишних пробелов):
«Уно, вист, нард, домино, реверси, мельница, монополия - настольные игры».
Ученик вычеркнул из списка название одной из настольных игр. Заодно он вычеркнул ставшие лишними запятые и пробелы — два пробела не должны идти подряд.
При этом размер нового предложения в данной кодировке оказался на 10 байтов меньше, чем размер исходного предложения. Напишите в ответе вычеркнутое название головного убора."         
                ],
                "answers": [
                    "Тюлень",
                    "Соликамск",
                    "Фата",
            "Мельница"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

В юнити этот код я перевожу в класс со структурой all_tasks с помощью такого кода:

```
public void initializeTasksDictionaries ()
    {
        string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/DataTask.game";
        
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path);

        string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        all_tasks = JsonUtility.FromJson<Tasks>(jsonString).all_tasks;
    }
```

И получаю ошибку:
`ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid escape character in string. UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type) (at <1386288601af43018501cce2912f52f4>:0)...`

То есть ошибка заключается в json файле, но там я ничего не нашел: все скобки на месте, все верные, запятые тоже...

Путем экспериментов, я выяснил, что ошибка появляется тогда, когда я добавляю перенос на новую строку? значит ли это в json файле я могу делать перенос строки только с помощью \n, но весь текст в файле писать в одну строку?

Comment: Переносы строк не должны влиять на парсинг JSON. Попробуйте более вменяемый JSON парсер - `Newtonsoft.Json`. Устанавливается из NuGet. Есть вероятность, что он проглотит это без ошибок. `JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject<...>(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените переводы на новую строку внутри строк (строка это то, что в `""`) на `\n`.

Comment: Могу ли я как-то сделать текст более человекочитаемым с помощью переводов? Или \n это вообще единственный способ?

Comment: @МаксимФисман никак, JSON предназначен для компьютеров и предполагается, что он будет создаваться и читаться компьютерами